# Image not showing in ToastNotification

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am building a notification service and I am currently facing an issue when trying to display any kind of image in it.
I am using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` and below is the code I am using to show build and show the notification.

```cs
static class NotificationTemplate
{
    public static ToastContentBuilder HelpDesk(string main_payload, string additional_data, string type)
    {
        return new ToastContentBuilder()
                  .AddArgument("type", "helpdesk")
                  .AddArgument("select", main_payload)
                  .AddText("Incoming ticket", AdaptiveTextStyle.Title)
                  .AddText(type, AdaptiveTextStyle.Header)
                  .AddAttributionText(additional_data)
                  .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/the-weather-is-nice-today/64/weather_11-64.png"))
                  .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                      .AddArgument("take", main_payload)
                      .SetContent("TAKE"))
                  .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                      .AddArgument("close", main_payload)
                      .SetContent("CLOSE"));
    }

}
```

The image I use in the `Uri` is valid(a test link, not the actual thing) and is shown when opening the link in a browser.
Below is a screenshot of the shown notification:
[image: Notification showing without image]

I am running `Windows 10` build `19045.3324`

Comment: Is your app packaged? IIRC, HTTP / HTTPS resources are supported when the app is packaged and manifested, specifying Internet capabilities, otherwise you use `ms-appdata:///local/`

Comment: It is not packaged. So I need to store the images locally ?

Comment: You can store image into local and update build type resouces

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853578/i-want-to-access-resources-in-uwp

Comment: @AnantDabhi is this the same for WinForms ? As I created an assets folder and added test.png to it. I then set the test.png build to `resource` and `copy if newer` and created the following path `ms-appx:///Assets/test.png` according to the link you sent, but now it doesn't even show the rest of the notification(text, buttons etc)

Comment: `ms-appx://` it's a schema that defines resources that come from the app's package. Your app is not packaged

Comment: I clearly stated that the app isn't packaged. Idk why Anant even suggested it

Comment: @Jimi How do I work around this ? What is the solution ?

Comment: IMO, the best thing you can do is to package your app. Nothing fancy, add a packaging Project, so your app gets manifested correctly. Add your Project's reference to the package, edit the manifest to specify Internet capabilities (and whatever else you find necessary)

Comment: I am wondering if this should work while in debug mode or do I have to use the package to install the app ?

Answer (score 3):

It's explicitly mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

> **ⓘ Important**
>
> Http images are supported only in packaged apps that have the internet
> capability in their manifest. Unpackaged apps don't support http
> images; you must download the image to your local app data, and
> reference it locally.

As you have mentioned you are not using a packaged app, then you must download the image yourself, either at design-time or run-time.

You can download it and add it to the solution and copy it to the output directory, or you can download and use it at run-time. For example:

```
static WebClient client = new WebClient();
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Logo.jpg");
    if(!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        var address = "https://picsum.photos/360/202?image=883";
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(address), fileName);
    }
    ToastContentBuilder builder = new ToastContentBuilder()
        .AddText("Lorem Ipsum!")
        .AddText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
        .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri(fileName));
    builder.Show();
}
```

**Note:** Not the concern of this question/answer, but to download the file, it's [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks) to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270371/3110834).

As mentioned in the documents, for packaged app, if internet access is enabled, you don't need to download the image and you can use the image url. To learn more, take a look at following resources:

- [Set up your desktop application for MSIX packaging in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Understanding how packaged desktop apps run on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

And yes, both solutions (without download For packaged apps, and with download for non-packaged apps) work on debug mode as well.